# Proof of Weinberg effective field theorem?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, s-matrix-theory, effective-field-theory

In the book [Effective field theory](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/8619)   at page 6 there is this Weinberg's theorem

> To any given order in perturbation theory, and for a given set of asymptotic states, the most general possible Lagrangian containing
> all terms allowed by the assumed symmetries will yield the most general $S$-matrix
> elements consistent with analyticity, perturbative unitarity, cluster
> decomposition and assumed symmetry principles.

This Weinberg theorem is found in many books and articles but  I never found a proof of it.
How we proof it?

Comment: The first few chapters (from memory, maybe chapters 2-5 or 2-6?) of Vol 1 of Weinberg's QFT textbook lays out the argument; essentially starting from analyticity, perturbative unitarity, cluster decomposition and symmetry, Weinberg constructs the form of the S-matrix and shows it follows from a Hamiltonian written in terms of fields. I am not sure whether or not this is strictly a "theorem" in a mathematical sense or more of a "folk theorem", but that's the basis of the statement.

Comment: Symmetries of what: of the "exact theory" or of one of its "effective" replacements?

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski The symmetries of the physics you are probing. For example, baryon number is a good symmetry in the Standard Model, and some proposed extensions of the SM respect this symmetry, so then you would write higher dimension operators respecting baryon number. However, some other theories like GUTs break baryon number, so if you are looking for low energy effects of GUTs you would include baryon-number-violating operators in your low energy effective theory (which would model, eg, proton decay).

Comment: Of course we don't know the symmetries of the "exact" theory so these are all symmetries of different effective field theories. (Although it's generally thought in a quantum theory of gravity there are no global symmetries, so under this logic there should be operators that break a lot of symmetries in the Standard Model as we know it today).